# PHP Imagettftext each word as separate image

Tags: php, word-wrap, imagettftext

When using imagettftext I can create a single line of text as one long image using imagecreatetruecolor:

```
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
```

This will display as much text in a single line as will fit in the dimensions 400x30px.

How can I separate each word into a new image?

I'd like each new word image next to the one before (perhaps with space between) and then to wrap to the container size.

Would it also be possible for it to wrap to the new dimensions of the page after the browser is resized? That sounds ambitious, but would be really handy!

Any help is greatly received.

Comment: Are you aware of client-side font techniques like `@font-face`? if it's just about generating some text, they're much better than doing this using `imagettftext()`

Comment: you can explode() the string and loop through it and create each image...

Answer (score 0):

First off, I can't come up with a reason for someone to generate a new image for every word in a string as it would take a long time to do and require lots of server resources.

But to answer your question, you should probably do some sort of a loop, here's a quick mockup.

```
<?php
    $string = "This is a string with spaces";

    foreach(explode(" ",$string) as $word){
    // Image generation code here
    }
?>
```

Comment: How can I make the new images follow on from the next one? 

Currently all the words layer on top of each other in one single image. 

I'm trying to incorporate your code into the Testing... example on the PHP manual page, where you say "//image generation code here" I have `imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $word);`

Comment: Well, yes, ofcourse, if you don't create and save every word as a seperate image the text will overlap. I guess what you meant was wrapping inside the given dimensions into multiple lines?

If so, you don't need to create multiple images, it doesnt work that way.

I'd sugest making a function that checks the length of given string and splits it after the last word that will fit in the dimensions, then write on the next line.

Comment: That sounds complicated!  
I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out, and I don't want to abuse that, but can you give me any pointers on how to do that?   
I've seen many 'functions' on the manual page [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) but I don't know what to do with them.  

Do you know of one (and how to use it) that would only output an image that is the size of the text? (plus a small border)  
What I don't want is for text that is too long for the image dimensions to be clipped which happened when I use imagecreatetruecolor dimensions with wordwrap